# Rails 5.2 asset pipeline not working in developemnt environemnt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets

I have created simple rails app. I have configured below setting developemnt.rb(default setting).

```
config.assets.debug = true
config.assets.quiet = true
```

when i am running the app in development mode i am getting below error.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "application.css" is not present in the asset pipeline.)
```

When I precompile in development. I am getting precompiled assets from **public** directory. But why i need to precompile in development.

```
RAILS_ENV=development rails assets:precompile
```

config/initializer/asset.rb

```
 # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
 Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'
 # Add additional assets to the asset load path.
 # Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Emoji.images_path
 # Add Yarn node_modules folder to the asset load path.
 Rails.application.config.assets.paths <<  Rails.root.join('node_modules')
 Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(application.js application.css test.css)
```

What is the mistake here?

**Answer:**
After debugging i found that some how  `config.assets.resolve_with` is going as **:manifest**  for development environment.

I updated same to **:environment** in development.rb

Answer (score 0):

In production, Rails precompiles these files to public/assets by default.

In developments it's not.

You could also add

`Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( application.css )`

to your `assets.rb`.

Comment: Tried still no luck

Comment: Hi @amer I have found the issue. please look at the updated anwer.

Comment: Great ! Good for you.